# count row cell and copy and paste

Tags: vba, loops, count, copy, row

I using my code for working with c# based macro soft
but i want do my macro only using VBA, not using c#
is it can do it? not using point?

1. Data in B2~Bxxxxx
2. my c# program do copy B2 cell value and paste another worksheets K3 cell
3. run macro under code

```
    Sub CopyRows()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    
     Dim bottomL As Long
     Dim x As Long
     bottomL = Sheets("Total").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: x = 1
     
     Dim c As Range
     Dim lr As Long
    
     lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     For Each c In Sheets("Total").Range("K1:K" & bottomL)
     If c.Value = "Inside" Then
     c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("filter").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
     x = x + 1
     End If
     Next c
     
    End Sub
```

4. then my c# program do select b3 and copy to otherworksheet k3 cell then run macro then loop that process and end be cell on Bxxxxx

anyone know that working only using VBA?

Thanks and Sorry for my Bad English

Answer (score 0):

In VBA make the full code like this:

```
Function CopyRows()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
  Application.EnableEvents = False 
  ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
  Dim bottomL As Long 
  Dim x As Long 
  bottomL = Sheets("Total").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  x = 1
  Dim c As Range Dim lr As Long
  lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
  For Each c In Sheets("Total").Range("K1:K" & bottomL) 
    If c.Value = "Inside" Then 
      c.EntireRow.Copy 
      Worksheets("filter").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 
       x = x + 1 
    End If  
  Next c
End Function 

Sub Main()
  Dim bottomB As Long 
  Dim y As Long 
  bottomB = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  For y = 2 To bottomB
    Range("B" & 2).Copy Worksheets("Total").Range("K3")
    CopyRows
  Next
End Sub
```

Then only run Sub Main().

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Wasif Hasan

I already using like this code i made

```
Sub dual()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    Dim i As Long
    Dim totalRows As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim Number As Long
    Dim nowRows As Long
    Dim bottomL As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim c As Range
    Dim lr As Long
    
    bottomL = Sheets("Total").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row: x = 1
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With Worksheets("List")
        'for looping
        totalRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        'index of row to add from
        lastRow = totalRows + 1 '<--| start pasting values one row below the last non empty one in column "B"

        'data starts at row #2
        For i = 2 To totalRows
            If .Cells(i, 2).Value > 0 Then
                Worksheets("List").Cells(i, "B").Copy
                Worksheets("Total").Range("K3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                lastRow = lastRow + Number
                    For Each c In Sheets("Total").Range("L1:L" & bottomL)
                    If c.Value = "Inside" Then
                    c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("filter").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    x = x + 1
                    End If
                    Next c
            End If
        Next i
    End With Application.ScreenUpdating = True ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True End Sub
```

but its lost many data at copy&paste
so it need wait paste done
so i using other program
is it any option to make waiting paste done?
Thnaks your Answer

Answer (score 0):

If it is not necessary to copy and paste than try not to use that command. It is faster to just use cell1.Value = cell2.Value.
In your case you should declare a variable to count the total amount of columns in b. Then use a loop to go through b2 up to bx.
Example:

dim i as Integer

dim j as Integer

j = 3



For i = 2 to totalCount


Worksheet.Cells(2, i).Value = Worksheet2.Cells(11, j)

j = j + 1


Next i

In the above 2 = Column B and 11 = Column K